# Although numpy is installed I get an "ModuleNotFoundError" if I try to use it

Tags: python, numpy

If i run `pip install numpy` then I get

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Users/aaditya/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.19.5)
```

But if I use `import numpy as np` in a python file then I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aaditya/Desktop/Blender_software/Blender_algo_exp/quantity_sol.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Although if I run `import numpy as np` in my terminal directly then it works. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You're running "blender".  Blender has its own Python interpreter built-in.  You need to get `numpy` installed in that version.

Comment: Blender is actually my folder name

Comment: OK, sorry.  Jumped to a conclusion.  Still, you must have multiple versions of Python installed.  It's the only explanation.  Are you running that by double-clicking on the .py file?

Comment: activate 3.8.5 where you running your program. You are running  you program outside of that enviornment

Comment: It's not important that you run your script in a python file or not, it's more important that you run the file/script in the correct environment. What/Where exactly did you run the `quantity_sol.py` file?

Comment: I was running the code via vscode

Comment: I have not created any environment in which I am running this code

Comment: @AadityaYadav that's likely the problem, you need to run your code in the same environment localed at `/Users/aaditya/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5` (the `.pyenv` in that path suggests `numpy` is installed in that PyEnv for Python version 3.8.5. The path `/Users/aaditya/Desktop/Blender_software/` does not have a `.pyenv` in the path, and the error suggests you don't have numpy installed system-wide, so either create the same PyEnv in your new project path (`/Users/aaditya/Desktop/Blender_software/`), move your project to the old `numpy` path, or open a new terminal and install `numpy` system-wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need restart Visual Code or Pycharm

Or you should check python IDE for Visual Studio

Another solution is run command

```
python3 -m pip install numpy
```